# OL3+osrm show route with instructions

Tags: openlayers, open-source-routing-machine

Could someone give me example how to create a route between two points using ol3 and osrm and give me the instructions (ex in 500m right etc).

I found this already of documenation: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#general-options

Comment: this is possible a duplicate. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524101/using-osrm-routing-in-openlayers-3-to-draw-polyines-on-the-map-along-the-directi/34589211#34589211

Comment: As Pavlos stated, this is a duplicate of the question quoted by him which contains a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

If OpenLayers is not a hard requirement there is https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine for Leaflet which support OSRM by default.

Looking at the current OpenLayers plugins there seems to be none that supports the OSRM 5.x HTTP API. Which means you will need to write this yourself.

Comment: I would have a look at leaflet

but i prefer to work with openlayers